# CSS not select not working with substring selector

Tags: html, css

I have several `<th>` tags in a table, and I want to change their color unless the first one. I tried css `:not` selector, but it is not working when put substring selector inside. It works only when I directly put the `id` of the element.
However, I want to make this more dynamic (e.g. not need to change the `id` everytime). How should I do this?

```
//This is not working
th[id*="header"]:not(th[id*="header0"])

//This is working
th[id*="header"]:not(#header0)
```

```css
/*
th[id*="header"]:not(th[id*="header0"]) {
  color: red;
}
*/

th[id*="header"]:not(#header0) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th id="header0">Header0</th>
    <th id="header1">Header2</th>
    <th id="header2">Header3</th>
    <th id="header3">Header4</th>
    <th id="header4">Header5</th>
    <th id="header5">Header6</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why not just use first-child? ie. `th:not(:first-child) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *suspect* that you are looking for something like this

```css
th[id^="header"]:not([id$="0"]) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th id="header0">Header0</th>
    <th id="header1">Header2</th>
    <th id="header2">Header3</th>
    <th id="header3">Header4</th>
    <th id="header4">Header5</th>
    <th id="header5">Header6</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Where `th[id^="header"]:not([id$="0"])` reads as:

Any th element with ID starting from "header" but not ending with "0".

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Sometimes the Header0 may not be my first -child.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying various method, why not use simple method like the following?

```
th{
  color: red;
}
th:first-child{
  color: black;
}
```

Which is more compatible than using like this:

```
th:not(:first-child) {
   color: red;
}
```

---

To answer your question:

```
//This is not working
th[id*="header"]:not(th[id*="header0"])
```

Because `th[id*="header"]` selects all th elements with id having header string anywhere and using the not selector you mean using `:not(th[id*="header0"])` will select the child element of `th[id*="header"]` which you don't have i.e. **th of th**. And even the `:not` selector won't work for complex selector. See this [reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors) to see the simple selector.

```
//This is working
th[id*="header"]:not(#header0)
```

This works because it says that you are not selecting `#header0` th element of the same header `th[id*="header"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first-child selector with not

```
th:not(:first-child) {
    color: red;
}
```